# Accessing inherited classe?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, oop

I have an observable collection called `players` containing a variety of `Player` objects. 
All objects inherit properties from the `Player` object but are distinct classes with some unique properties such as `Goalkeeper` and `Defender` etc

How can I check the type of object in the observable collection and change its unique properties accordingly?

```
 foreach (Player p in players)
            {
                if(p.GetType().Name == "Goalkeeper")
                {
                  p.Saves == 100;
                }
                else if (p.GetType().Name == "Defender")
                {
                    p.Tackles = 50;
                }



            }
```

Comment: Apologies, es there was a typo but this doesnt solve the issue. `Goalkeeper` object have the Saves property whilst `Defender` objects do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `is` and `as`:

```
foreach (var p in players)
{
    if (p is Goalkeeper)
    {
        var goalie = p as Goalkeeper;
        goalie.Saves == 100;
    }
    else if (p is Defender)
    {
        var defender = p as Defender;
        defender.Tackles = 50;
    }
}
```

As a note: C#7 (available in Visual Studio 2017) has some new syntax to simplify these to remove the need to have separate `is` and `as` statements, as well as some enhancements to the `switch` statement.

```
switch(p)
{
    case Goalkeeper goalie:
        goalie.Saves == 100;
        break;

    case Defender defender:
        defender.Tackles = 50;
        break;

    /* ... */
    default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown Player Type");
        break;
}
```